# Fix text position in columns in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, columns, presentations

I'm doing a presentation where I want to have some text on the left side and an image on the right side, but when either the text or the image aren't identical (same size, lenght, etc.) the text renders in a different position and when cycling through the frames/slides in a presentation mode the text seems to jump and it feels very sloppy. How do I make the text static no matter the size of the image next to it or the lenght of the text?

Simplified code (left the the packages, not sure if they modify the default behaviour in this context):

```
%% DOCUMENT CLASS %%
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

%% PACKAGES %%
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=science]{biblatex} %authortitle
%\usepackage[backend=biber, babel=other, style=iso-numeric]{biblatex} %authortitle
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=iso-numeric, babel=other, urldate=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\small}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}

%% FORMATING %%
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{//}
%% BEGIN DOCC %% 
\begin{document}
\section{section title}
\frame{ \frametitle{frame title}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.3\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item one
        \item Item two
        \item Item three 
        \item Item four
        \item Item five
        \item Item six
      \end{enumerate}

    \column{0.7\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics<1>[width=1\textwidth]{src/img.png}%
      \only<1>{\caption{caption one}}
      \includegraphics<2>[width=0.45\textwidth]{src/img2.png}%
      \only<2>{\caption{caption 2}}

      \end{figure}
  \end{columns}
}

%% END DOCC %% 
\end{document}
```

This gif below shows the unwanted behaviour I described above:

[image: Text jumping between frames]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get rid of jumping is to make the frame and columns top aligned:

```
%% DOCUMENT CLASS %%
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

%% PACKAGES %%
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=science]{biblatex} %authortitle
%\usepackage[backend=biber, babel=other, style=iso-numeric]{biblatex} %authortitle
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=iso-numeric, babel=other, urldate=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\small}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}

%% FORMATING %%
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{//}
%% BEGIN DOCC %% 
\begin{document}
\section{section title}
\frame{ \frametitle{frame title}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item one
        \item Item two
        \item Item three 
        \item Item four
        \item Item five
        \item Item six
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}      
      \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.6\textheight}
      \centering
      \includegraphics<1>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \only<1>{\caption{caption one}}
      \includegraphics<2>[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \only<2>{\caption{caption 2}}
      \end{overlayarea}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
}

%% END DOCC %% 
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you don't want this, you could use the `overlayarea` environment:

```
%% DOCUMENT CLASS %%
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

%% PACKAGES %%
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=science]{biblatex} %authortitle
%\usepackage[backend=biber, babel=other, style=iso-numeric]{biblatex} %authortitle
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=iso-numeric, babel=other, urldate=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\small}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}

%% FORMATING %%
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{//}
%% BEGIN DOCC %% 
\begin{document}
\section{section title}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{frame title}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item one
        \item Item two
        \item Item three 
        \item Item four
        \item Item five
        \item Item six
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}      
      \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.6\textheight}
      \centering
      \includegraphics<1>[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \only<1>{\caption{caption one}}
      \includegraphics<2>[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \only<2>{\caption{caption 2}}
      \end{overlayarea}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

%% END DOCC %% 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some unrelated notes:

- no need to load `url` or `hyperref`, beamer will automatically load the later
- loading `float` makes not much sense, beamer does not have a floating mechanism
- no need for `graphicx` and `xcolor`, beamer loads them automatically
- be careful with `setspace`, changing the spacing can have surprising effects in beamer as beamer assumes to know the spacing for some things...
- Using `caption` is not always necessary, most things can be done with beamer's own caption mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the latter option now and it works just how I wanted it. Thanks for those other tips aswell, I'm new to Latex and just ported my template for normal pdfs to a beamer template.

Comment: @mamimom892 Presentations are a very different medium than normal text documents. Consequently beamer does many things differently than normal classes. I suggest start with a clean presentation and only bring over the settings from your normal document, which you really need. This avoids a lot of problems in your presentation.

Comment: Alright, I'll take your advice and start clean.

Comment: @mamimom892 Have fun with beamer!